# how to deploy host name for the website in iis bindings?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have problem with giving host name to a website in `iis` bindings option.When I browse the website by binding the website with empty host name,it can be seen in the browser.

But when i write the host name for the same website by assigning it in the binding option it gives an error "***Server not found***"

I also edited the hosts file in '`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`".

So please help me to assign host name to the website.I have stucked with this problem for three days

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information about the 'hostname' ? Is it a domain name ? A DNS alias ? When it works, do you reach the website with its server name ? When it don't work, do you reach the website with a different url ? On which port ?

Comment: What version of IIS? IIS6 or 7/7.5?

Answer (score 0):

If you edited the host file, the line that you added should look something like:

127.0.0.1 [Tab] www.hostname.com

Also in IIS when you do "Edit Bindings" you will have to put the host name in the correct field. Then do Start -> Run -> Type "iisreset" to restart your IIS and then do a Start -> Run -> Type "cmd" and try pinging www.hostname.com and make sure that the response comes from your local machine.

Also make sure that you are actually typing the "www" in your web browser.

Hope this helps!